# Chrome and Edge duplicating bookmarks

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge

This problem started a few days ago for no apparent reason (no change to the system). I usually use Chrome and it started sort of duplicated my bookmarks, not an exact duplication but the bookmarks appeared in different places in the folder structure. If I delete the duplicate they reappeared after a few seconds. I tried tuning off bookmark synchronisation but that didn't help. So I exported the bookmarks after deleing the duplicates and before the duplication and imported this (and other settings) into Edge, but that started doing exactly the same, duplicating the bookmarks/favourites.
The problem appeared on a Windows 10 PC but the duplicates are also in Chrome on my iPhone and iPad. I'm up-to-date on updates on all devices.
How can I stop the duplication process?

Comment: If Windows 10, go to Settings, Accounts, Sync your settings and turn that feature OFF.  Also turn Sync OFF in Chromium Edge and Chrome settings.  I have Chromium Edge, Chrome, and iPhone and nothing is sync'd .

Comment: That has stopped the duplication but stops bookmarks added to one device being seen on another.

Comment: Bookmarks are part of duplication so when needed I move bookmarks. But I do not need this very much. I will post an answer as this has helped you.

Comment: It didn't work anyway, today everything has been duplicated again!

Comment: Even when I have sync turned off and delete all the bookmark they soon come bac, this times four fold!

Comment: I've now found the problem it was the iCloud sync extension for Chrome, when I deleted it and restored my bookmarks the duplication stopped.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10, Chromium Edge, Chrome and Windows settings, machines can be set to sync settings, bookmarks and other things.

I generally (for myself) did not find this really useful but some people do. So I turned these settings off. Nice that we can set our own preference.

Go to Settings, Accounts, Sync your settings and turn that feature OFF.

Also turn Sync OFF in Chromium Edge and Chrome settings. I have Chromium Edge, Chrome, and iPhone and nothing is sync'd .

Here is more information from Microsoft. Syncing continues to be a work in progress.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/about-sync-settings-on-windows-10-devices-deebcba2-5bc0-4e63-279a-329926955708

Also, here is a screen shot of individual sync settings. You may well have seen this already.

[image]

I trust this is useful for you.

This works for all my machines here. If there are still issues, it is more difficult, because you need to find the machine that is causing issues.

Comment: Still have the problem after doing this.

Comment: More than one machine has to be involved, so you need to find the one with the issues.  Default install tends to Sync.

Comment: Are you sure this applies to Chrome bookmarks? First of all, it says _"Sync your settings"_ and bookmarks aren't settings. Also how would this work with multiple Chrome profiles? Why would Google implement this, considering that they have their own account sync mechanism which they're promoting quite aggresively?

Comment: I looked at Chrome, have Sync turned Off in Gmail, and most other sync services turned Off as well.  I basically went to my 3 machines and turned syncing Off on all of them. This is very important for Microsoft Accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Chrome: Bookmarks duplicated into the thousands. If I deleted them, they popped right back up. I had Chrome bookmarks synced. Did a bunch of google searches, tried every complex solution I found.

The problem in my case was that I also had Apple's iBookmark extension enabled. Simple as that.

Google and Apple were fighting each other to the death in the cloud. I was an innocent victim. But I survived. Now I'm a survivor.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).